# Storing in todo list

Tags: jquery, html, css

After user input some tasks and click "Add button" I want new items to be saved in local storage.
Here is a code below: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ovesyan19/mcm36/1/

**HTML**

```
<form class="new_item">
        <input type="text" class="text_field" name="server_input" id="text_field" placeholder="Write a new task here..." onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Write a new task here...'" />
        <input type="submit" class="add_btn" value="Add" />
</form> 

<div class="items">
    <ul id="tasks_list" class="sortable">
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myTasks = localStorage.getItem("tasks");
if(myTasks===undefined || myTasks===null)
{
    myTasks = [];
}
myTasks.push(task);
localStorage.setItem("tasks", myTasks);
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: Well you have posted exact same question for the third time. You don't show any effort to try to resolve your issue by yourself, just beging for other guy to code it for you. You shouldn't last long here on SO...

Comment: @A.Wolff, that was rude isn't it?

Comment: @AmitJoki IMHO, not enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
var myTasks = localStorage.getItem("tasks");
if(myTasks===undefined || myTasks===null)
{
   myTasks = [];
}
myTasks.push(task);
localStorage.setItem("tasks", myTasks);
```

should be:

```
var myTasks = localStorage.getItem("tasks") || []
if(myTasks != [])
    myTasks = JSON.parse(myTasks);
myTasks.push(task);
localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(myTasks));
```

`localStorage` holds only strings. So, you have to convert the array to JSON using `JSON.stringify` and then you can parse the same by `JSON.parse('json')`

Comment: When I run this and reload page it still not saving anything. Where can I see the result of it storing the tasks? Thank you!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ovesyan19/gp5Ew/  Here is and updated version, does it work for you?

Comment: @user3537476, of course it works for me and you. You can try localStorage.getItem('tasks') from the console and seee that it returns json after you've added a task